# Related to random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

I am working on research project related to wireless communication wherein there is extensive use of concept of random variables.

I have the following equation: $X = h_0h_{1_{n}}$ ---(1)

where, $h_0$ is Nakagami-$m$ random variable with mean power $\Omega_0$ and $h_{1_{n}}$ is Gaussian noise with mean power $\sigma^2$.

My query is what will be variance of $X$ of equation (1).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what happens when you apply the definition of variance to $X$?

Comment: Are $h_0$ and $h_{1_n}$ independent?

Comment: yes sir....they are independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to reformulate the variables at play to make sure I got it right:

$$
h_0 \sim \text{Nak}(m, \Omega_0) \\
h_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)
$$

Assuming the variables $h_0$ and $h_1$ are independent (and hence we can factor the expectation of the product) we have:

$$
\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(h_0 h_1) = \mathbb{E}(h_0)\mathbb{E}(h_1)=0 \\
\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\mathbb{E}(h_0^2 h_1^2) = \mathbb{E}(h_0^2)\mathbb{E}(h_1^2)=\Omega_0 \sigma^2 \\
\text{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-[\mathbb{E}(X)]^2=\Omega_0 \sigma^2
$$

where for the second moment we used the fact that for $Z\sim \text{Nak}(m, \Omega)$ we have $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\Omega$

Comment: Thank u so much sir for ur response...